# Using Reflection in maven project

Tags: reflection, maven-2

Here is mavenized project stucture

```
Proj1
--Module 1
----Submodule 1
------Submodule1-child1
------com.module1.submodule1.child1
------Submodule1-child2
------com.module1.submodule1.child2
----Submodule 2
------com.module1.submodule2
--Module 2
----Submodule 3
------com.module2.submodule3
----Submodule 4
------com.module2.submodule4
```

In each submodule there are no. of classes.

What I suppose to do is create one more class in submodule 4, which will list out all classes in submodule1 and its child modules. I also need to load any of those classes.

I am familiar with reflection, but I am stuck with maven. How can I put dependency for module1 in my pom, so all classes under module1 and its submodule will be in classpath

Comment: My question might be confusing, what I need is all classes in Submodule 1, or its child module available in classpath

Answer (score 1):

Add a dependency element to the POM for each of the modules that you want to include.  Once the dependencies are defined, all of the classes will be available for your code to load.

Comment: I can add say Module1 dependency in pom, but I m not suppose to add submodule depenecy everytime submodule created ( imagine 12 developer created 1-2 submodule per week).  Anyway I solved problem by using Apache Common FileUtils to find required files. And then use ProcessBuilder to run 'mvn app:run' command.  Thanks for answering.